# c++: vector of class instances, search by class member values failed

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have the following program where I defined a vector of class Point. I pushed into this vector five Point instances, with their Ids. Then I tried to search by Id but didn't get the expected result. The following program didn't return anything.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int id;
public:
    Point(){}
    void setId(int k){ id=k; }
    int GetId() { return id; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Point> datasets;
    for(int i=0; i< 5; ++i){
        Point temp;
        temp.setId(i);
        datasets.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        if (datasets[i].GetId() ==4){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `didn't get the expected result` What result did you expect, and what did you observe? `program didn't return anything` What do you mean? `int main()` definitely returns *something* - it can't not to.

Comment: ahhhh. I was so stupid... I should use cout << instead of return. sorry...

Comment: Can I ask another question? I ever tried to define vector this way: vector<Point> datasets[5], (assign the length), but it reported errors. Why couldn't I define a vector with its length? Thank you

Comment: `vector<Point> datasets[5]` defines an array of five `vector<Point>`s - not a single `vector<Point>` of size 5. For the latter, you want `vector<Point> datasets(5);`

Comment: You should initialize `id` in the constructor. `Point(int id) : id(id) {}`. And if you keep the default constructor, initialize `id` with 0: `Point() : id(0) {}`.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianHackl. so with the constructor, I don't need to define a setId() function? Will remember to initialize the member variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is probably working just fine, I think you're mixing up `return` with `cout` to actually print it out to the console, currently you're not printing anything and you're just returning `i` to the OS because you use return in `main`, making it a status code.

To see the output, use `cout`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Point{
        private:
                int id;
        public:
                Point(){}
                void setId(int k){id=k;}
                int GetId(){return id;}
};


int main()
{
        vector<Point> datasets;
        for(int i=0; i< 5; ++i){
        Point temp;
        temp.setId(i);
        datasets.push_back(temp);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                if (datasets[i].GetId() ==4){
                        cout << "i is : " << i << endl;
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

**Edit to answer OP's comment:**

use : `vector<Point> datasets(5);`

Comment: Can I ask another question? I ever tried to define vector this way: vector<Point> datasets[5], (assign the length), but it reported errors. Why couldn't I define a vector with its length? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you arent printing any thing because you put return i after for loop

its certain that you wont got any result

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Point{
        private:
                int id;
        public:
                Point(){}
                void setId(int k){id=k;}
                int GetId(){return id;}
};



 int main()
    {
            vector<Point> datasets;
            for(int i=0; i< 5; ++i){
            Point temp;
            temp.setId(i);
            datasets.push_back(temp);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                    if (datasets[i].GetId() ==4){
                            cout<<i<<endl;
                    }
            }
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

you can use :  `datasets.insert(datasets.begin()+i,temp);`

instead of  `datasets.push_back(temp);`

for more flexibility in adding elements at the index i in vector class